# Discord.js DiscordAPIError: Missing Permissions ---Which permission is missing?

Tags: discord, discord.js

I have a bot which is supposed to create a channel under a specific category and then add two users to this channel.

The following bit of code is "supposed" to work and add user two, but fails with DiscordAPIError: Missing Permissions.
What I can't figure out is the actual permission required for this?

```
function addUserToChannel(ch, user, altCh) {
  console.log(user.username,"sendmsg",ch.permissionsFor(client.user).has("MANAGE_CHANNELS", false)); //returns true
  if (!ch.permissionsFor(user).has("SEND_MESSAGES", false)) {
    console.log("User", user.username, "lacks view-channel permission");
    ch.updateOverwrite(user, { //fails here obviously
      SEND_MESSAGES: true,
      VIEW_CHANNEL: true
    });
  } else {
    console.log("WARN:", user.username, " already in channel ", ch.name);
    altCh.send(user.toString() + " join conversation here: " + ch.toString());
  }
}
```

The channel is created using the following code:

```
function createPrivateChannel(guild, convo, user) {
  let everyoneRole = guild.roles.cache.find(r => r.name === "@everyone");
  
  let parent = guild.channels.cache.find(ch => {
    //console.log(ch.id,secret.convoCat.id);
    return ch.id == secret.convoCat.id;
  });
 
  return guild.channels.create(convo.chName, {
    type: "text",
    parent: parent,
    permissionOverwrites: [
      {
        id: everyoneRole.id, //private channel
        deny: ["VIEW_CHANNEL", "SEND_MESSAGES"]
      }, 
      {
        id: client.user.id, //bot permissions
        allow: [  "VIEW_CHANNEL",  "SEND_MESSAGES",  "READ_MESSAGE_HISTORY",  "MANAGE_CHANNELS" ]
      },
      {
        id: user.user.id, //a different user
        allow: ["VIEW_CHANNEL", "SEND_MESSAGES", "READ_MESSAGE_HISTORY"]
      }
    ]
  });
}
```

Comment: I added a catch handler to process the error message and found that there's an error code: 50013 if that's of any help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the [Discord documentation for the 'Edit Channel Permissions' route](https://discord.com/developers/docs/resources/channel#edit-channel-permissions) (which is what `updateOverwrite` ultimately uses):

> Requires the `MANAGE_ROLES` permission. Only permissions your bot has in the guild or channel can be allowed/denied (unless your bot has a `MANAGE_ROLES` overwrite in the channel).

Comment: Apparently "MANAGE_CHANNEL" means something different than what I understood it to be...